# Centralizar um label em um badge

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Não estou conseguindo centralizar um label dentro de uma badge. Parece que o label está fora do badge. Veja o código:

```
<Grid      
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"      
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Operacional"     
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"   
    x:Class="Operacional.BadgeView" 
        Padding="5"
        Margin="1"
        HeightRequest="16"     
        WidthRequest="32">

    <local:CircleView x:Name="BadgeCircle"
                      HeightRequest="16" 
                      WidthRequest="32" 
                      CornerRadius="16" 
                      VerticalOptions="Start" 
                      HorizontalOptions="Start" />

    <Label x:Name="BadgeLabel"
           TextColor="White" 
           VerticalOptions="Start"           
           HorizontalOptions="Start" 
           VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
           FontSize="10"/>
</Grid>
```

ese é o behind

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class BadgeView : Grid
    {
        public static BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Text", typeof(string), typeof(BadgeView), "0", propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) =>
        {
            var view = (BadgeView)bindable;
            view.BadgeLabel.Text = (string)newVal;
        });

        public static BindableProperty BadgeColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create("BadgeColor", typeof(Color), typeof(BadgeView), Color.Blue, propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) =>
        {
            var view = (BadgeView)bindable;
            view.BadgeCircle.BackgroundColor = (Color)newVal;
        });

        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(TextProperty, value);
            }
        }
        public Color BadgeColor
        {
            get
            {
                return (Color)GetValue(BadgeColorProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(BadgeColorProperty, value);
            }
        }
        public BadgeView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BadgeLabel.Text = Text;
            BadgeCircle.BackgroundColor = BadgeColor;
        }
    }
```

o screenshot abaixo mostra como aparece no app
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta mudar o `HorizontalOptions` e `VerticalOptions` do Label dentro do Grid para `Center`. Eu recomendaria também deixar claro nos elementos dentro do Grid qual a posição deles:

```
<Grid      
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"      
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Operacional"     
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"   
    x:Class="Operacional.BadgeView" 
    Padding="5"
    Margin="1"
    HeightRequest="16"     
    WidthRequest="32">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <local:CircleView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                      x:Name="BadgeCircle"
                      HeightRequest="16" 
                      WidthRequest="32" 
                      CornerRadius="16" 
                      VerticalOptions="Start" 
                      HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
           x:Name="BadgeLabel"
           TextColor="White" 
           VerticalOptions="Center"           
           HorizontalOptions="Center" 
           VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
           FontSize="10"/>
</Grid>
```

O `Grid` é um dos Layouts que permitem sobreposição de Views, diferentemente do `StackLayout`, por exemplo. Os componentes dentro dele se organizarão em um esquema linha-coluna de acordo com a definição da localização e os componentes declarados por último ficam sobre os anteriores. Quando essa localização nao é explícita fica mais difícil entender a organização visual dos componentes no layout no caso de precisar acrescentar ou alterar as views posteriormente.

Para conceber melhor a disposição do layout, é interessante também habilitar a opão de `Mostar limites do layout` nas opções de desenvolvedor do android.

**Edição 1:**
No seu caso, é necessário definir o tamanho da linha e coluna da grid, pois quando omitido a view ocupa todo o espaço disponível, mas você precisa que ocupe somente o espaço necessário para comportar seu label e circle view.

Comment: Isso eu já havia feito e não rola. O texto vai para o centro da imagem e não do badge. Veja, tenho um badge em cima de uma imagem.

Comment: @pnet veja a edição. Se não estava funcionando é pq a grid está com as linhas e colunas expandindo para as dimensões do pai.

Comment: Eu não imaginei em redefinir o grid. Posicionei, mas em vão, pois não havia a redefinição. Valeu mais uma vez, Diego!!